# Android bottom left corner of relative layout in the same position as the center of an image

Tags: android

I have a layout with a rectangular image and a relative layout that has an image and an textview. This layout will be included in another layout.
I want that the left bottom corner of the layout is in the same position as the center of my rectangular image.

In the android studio design preview I've achieved this with the following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_center_image"
            android:src="@drawable/my_center_image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:id="@+id/placeholder"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@null"/>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/second_placeholder"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placeholder"
            android:layout_above="@+id/placeholder">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/my_image"
                android:background="@drawable/my_image"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In a real device this is not showing properly and the best I could achieve that mimics what I want is the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_center_image"
            android:src="@drawable/my_center_image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/placeholder"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/my_image"
                android:background="@drawable/my_image"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone help me understand what should I do so I can place the bottom left corner of a layout in the center of an image?

Comment: `what should I do so I can place the bottom left corner of a layout in the center of an image?` You could place a generic View (1dp wide and 1dp high) in the center of the screen. Put the ImageView also in the center. The generic View is invisible but must have a unique ID. Then set the layout to the right and the top of the View. It only sounds complicate, but it's not. It just makes use of the relativity inherited by the RelativeLayout children.

Comment: Hi Der Golen. Thanks for the first suggestion. That removes some usefulness code :) Has you can see in the first xml, `@+id/placeholder` is there to try to achieve what you suggested. unfortunately, it is not doing what is expected

Comment: Would you like to try out my code?

Comment: Also, I noticed that the TextView and the image are overlayed in the center of the second RelativeLayout. Is it the desired effect or the image could be on a side of the text? In this case, you could get rid of both the RelativeLayout and the ImageView and incorporate the image inside the TextView as a compound drawable.

Answer (score 1):

`What should I do so I can place the bottom left corner of a layout in the center of an image?`

You could place a generic View (1dp wide and 1dp high) in the center of the screen.
Put the ImageView also in the center.
The generic View is invisible but must have a unique ID.
Then set the layout to the right and the top of the View.

As shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/my_center_view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_center_image"
        android:src="@drawable/my_center_image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="my_center_view"
        android:layout_above="my_center_view"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_image"
            android:background="@drawable/my_image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20"
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="10dp"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It only sounds complicate, but it's not.
It just makes use of the relativity inherited by the RelativeLayout children.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the late response. I've realized that I was including this layout in another and changing the parent height to `match_parent` instead of  `wrap_content` solved my problem.